# opendir on ssh2 never stops

Tags: php, php-7, opendir, readdir, libssh2

I need to fetch some files from the root directory of a distant server through ssh, the local machine uses php7. I've made this script:

```
<?php
$strServer = "my-server.com";
$strServerPort = "22";
$strServerUsername = "my.username";
$strServerPassword = "my-password";
$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);
if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword)) {
    $files = array();
    $resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);
    $dirHandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($resSFTP) . "/");
    while ($dirHandle && ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) !== false) {
        if ($file == "." || $file == "..") {
            continue;
        }
        $strData = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($resSFTP) . "/" . $file);
        file_put_contents('/path/to/dir/' . $file, $strData);
    }
    ssh2_exec($resConnection, 'exit');
    unset($resConnection);
}

die;
```

It works, i.e. the files are fetched, but the script never stops.
If I knew the name of the file to fetch, the script would then be:

```
if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword)) {
    $files = array();
    $resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);
    $file = 'name_of_the_file.xlsx';
    $strData = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($resSFTP) . "/" . $file);
    file_put_contents('/path/to/dir/' . $file, $strData);
}
```

and then the file is fetch and the script stops at the end of its execution.

I cannot use phpseclib as it requires composer and I can't use it on the locale machine.

What can I do to `opendir()` and `readdir()` without having the script running infinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to break after your `file_put_contents`

for example:

```
if (file_put_contents('/path/to/dir/' . $file, $strData) !== false) {
    break;
}
```

or as a best approach you may use `closedir` directly after putting your data

```
do {
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..") {
        continue;
    }
    $strData = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($resSFTP) . "/" . $file);
    if (file_put_contents('/path/to/dir/' . $file, $strData)) {
        break;
    }
} while ($dirHandle && ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) !== false);

closedir($dirHandle);
```

Comment: `closedir` is definitely the way to go, but if I put it inside the `while` only the first file is fetched. If I put it after the `while` all files are fetched and the script stops. If you could edit your answer in order to integrate that I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: so your butting it outside the loop solves it ? however if you need to do the same with another approach , you may count the file and if the index equal to the count then close the dir;

Comment: yep, `closedir` outside of the loop works for me, just what I needed :)